# Make this table

Tags: tables, tabularx

I have to make the table in the figure, but I get several errors. Could you explain what are my mistakes, please? (I did not put the numbers in my code...I want to just understand how this works)

[image]

```
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {cccccc}
\bottomrule
Regione & Assistiti & di cui over 65 & di cui under 65 & % anziani & % under 65
\midrule
Italia & x & x & x & x& x //
Nord & x & x & x & x& x //
Centro & x & x & x & x& x //
Sud & x & x & x & x& x //
Basilicata & x & x & x & x& x //
\bottomrule
end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You should not use `//` instead of `\\ `.

Comment: and you should write `\%` instead of `%` otherwise LaTeX considers the following words as comments

Comment: also the options on the align are {lrrrrr} because you want first column left aligned and tho others right and not centered. Or you have to look at `siunitx` package to align on "." the numbers

Comment: and don't use `tabularx` if you don't have an `X` column type

Comment: Also, at the top of a table, preferably (for spacing reasons) put a `\toprule`.

Comment: @CarLaTeX, I don't get when you suggest me not to use "tabularx". Why?

Comment: @koleygr why do you suggest me to use {lrrrrr}?

Comment: @Alwayslearning Because if you don't have a `X` column, to use it is useless.

Comment: What do you mean by "x column"?

Comment: Alwayslearning Run the answer of @CarLaTeX... and then replace all with "c" and rerun... Look how the contents of the table will be aligned during the changes...

Comment: @Alwayslearning The `X` column cre­ates a para­graph-like col­umn whose width au­to­mat­i­cally ex­pands so that the de­clared width of the en­vi­ron­ment is filled. (Two X columns to­gether share out the avail­able space be­tween them, and so on.) See here: https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx

Comment: I suggest you to take a fast look here: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables from the beggining until the basic examples (including them) and then look at the `tabularx` section (if not looked at @CarLaTeX's more complete suggestion)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As we said in comments:

1. you should use `\\`, not `//` at the and of the table rows
2. `%` is a special char for LaTeX, you should write `\%` if you use it as a percentage, otherwise LaTeX considers what follows `%` as a comment
3. at the top of a table, for spacing reasons, you should use `\toprule`, not `\bottomrule` (that's why they have named them in that way)
4. you should not use `tabularx` if you don't have an `X` column type.

To explain better the last point, look at these examples:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
    In the following example, since the table is longer than the line width
    (we have an \verb|Overfull \hbox| error), the lines stop before the text
    ends:

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
        \toprule
        Don't try this at home, this is wrong! & Non fatelo, è sbagliato!\\
        \midrule
        Example of wrong use of \texttt{tabularx} & Esempio di un uso sbagliato di \texttt{tabularx}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

    In the following example, since the table is too much shorter than the
    line width, the lines go too much ahead w.r.t. the text:

    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{cc}
        \toprule
        This is wrong! & Questo è sbagliato!\\
        \midrule
        Wrong use & Uso sbagliato\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}

    Whereas, with \verb|X| columns:
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
        \toprule
        Try this at home, this is correct! & Questo si può fare, è giusto!\\
        \midrule
        Example of correct use of \texttt{tabularx} & Esempio di un uso corretto di \texttt{tabularx}\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center} 
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{XX}
        \toprule
        This is correct! & Questo è corretto!\\
        \midrule
        Correct use & Uso corretto\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Applying all that, here is a working code (since your table is lager than the line width I added `\footnotesize` to make the font smaller).

For the alignment, please note that `l` means left, `r` right, and `c` center.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\footnotesize\begin{tabular}{lrrrrr}
\toprule
Regione & Assistiti & di cui over 65 & di cui under 65 & \% anziani & \% under 65\\
\midrule
Italia & x & x & x & x& x \\
Nord & x & x & x & x& x \\
Centro & x & x & x & x& x \\
Sud & x & x & x & x& x \\
Basilicata & x & x & x & x& x \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course there are other solutions, here is an example with `tabularx`. Since the `X` column is ragged right by default, I created a new column type `R` to have the columns ragged left.

`*5R` is a shorcut for `RRRRR`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\raggedleft\arraybackslash}X}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{l*5R}
\toprule
Regione & Assistiti & di cui over 65 & di cui under 65 & \% anziani & \% under 65\\
\midrule
Italia & x & x & x & x& x \\
Nord & x & x & x & x& x \\
Centro & x & x & x & x& x \\
Sud & x & x & x & x& x \\
Basilicata & x & x & x & x& x \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! May I know why do you use (1) \begin{center} (2) {lrrrrr}

Comment: @Alwayslearning The `center` environment centers your table. You can also use `table` environment if you have a caption.

Comment: @Alwayslearning, the {lrrrrr} corresponds to the outline of the columns within the table. You have 6 columns and they are outlined "left", "right", "right", "right", "right", "right", just like in your example. Change one of these letters to "c" (stands for center) and see what happens!

Comment: @Alwayslearning See also Zarko's answer, he added the treatment of columns with numbers.

Comment: Now I check, thanks! There is a problem with the previous example instead. Namely, the horizontal lines do not look like the table in the figure, where the first and the last lines are drawn "strongly" (which is the effect that jelds "bottomrule", if I am not wrong.)

Comment: @Alwayslearning Try to enlarge the image on your pdf viewer. I see them correctly.

Comment: "Since the X column is centered by default" - did I miss some update? It used to be ragged right...

Comment: @TeXnician Ops, I'll correct immediately, all these comments made me confuse...

Comment: @CarLaTeX, thank you again; however, if I add text above the table, I get too much space between this text and the table.

Comment: Ok, no problem. I forgot to insert \\

Comment: @Alwayslearning instead of using \\, leave a blank line.

Answer (score 5):

considering all comments below question ... and add some my suggestions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

%-------------------------------- show page layout, only for test
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\sisetup{group-minimum-digits=4,
         group-separator={.},
         output-decimal-marker={,}}
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}
                             l
                        *{2}{S[table-format=6.0]}
                             S[table-format=5.0]
                        *{2}{S[table-format=2.2]}
                             }
 \toprule
Regione & {Assistiti} & {di cui over 65} & {di cui under 65} & {\% anziani} & {\% under 65} \\
    \midrule
Italia  & 123456      & 12345            & 1234              & 12,34        & 12,34         \\
Nord    & 12345       & 123456           & 123               & 12,34        & 12,34         \\
Centro  & 123456      & 12345            & 12345             & 12,34        & 12,34         \\
Sud     & 123456      & 12345            & 1234              & 12,34        & 12,34         \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

added red lines are only for show page layout.

Comment: in the first shot i load wrong version of code (with missing end :-( ) and wrong image. now this is corrected. is now table still not acceptable to you? if it, please show us, how you will do :-)

Comment: @CarLaTeX... I show it and deleted my comment... In Greek too (:P)

Comment: It is fine! Sorry for hurrying to comment before really understand (my problem is what CarLaTeX understood)

Comment: @koleygr, thank you for pointing to problem of my code. fortunately i observe this problem almost in the same time as you ... and try to put my cyber chaos in some order :-). i understood your comment very positive and in my response try to challenge/encourage you, to write (better) solution :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx} {\textwidth} {cccccc}
\hline
Regione & Assistiti & di cui over 65 & di cui under 65 & \% anziani & \% under 65 \\
\hline
Italia      & x & x & x & x & x \\
Nord        & x & x & x & x & x \\
Centro      & x & x & x & x & x \\
Sud         & x & x & x & x & x \\
Basilicata  & x & x & x & x & x \\
\hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: it does not do the job well

Comment: It works...I forgot to add the package before. Thanks!

Comment: 1) As already said, using `tabularx` without an `X` column is useless. 2) Due to 1), the last columns header goes outside the table because the table itself is larger than the text width.